# Nodejs: how to send two commands on TCP net socket using Nodejs net.socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I have two commands to send to server, first move forward, get the acknowledgment and then send next command move backward. I have written two separate java script files do achieve this. Can it is possible to write in single function. I am trying below code but only move forward command is sent to server.

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 1850;

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
    client.write('READER_FWD');
    //client.end();
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('DATA: ' + data);
    //client.destroy();
    // 

    if (data == 'ACK')
    {
        console.log('DATA1: ' + data);
        client.end();
        console.log('DATA2: ' + data);
        client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
            console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
            client.write('READER_BWD');
            //client.end();
            console.log('DATA3: ' + data);
        });

    }
    client.end();
});

client.on('end', function() {
    console.log('disconnected from server');
});

client.on('error', function(err) {
   console.log(err)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the code, as you rightly pointed out connection is getting close while writing, i have added some delay.

```
var net = require('net');


var config = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 1850
};

var move = {
    forward: 'READER_FWD',
    backward: 'READER_BWD'
};

var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect({
        host: config.host,
        port: config.port
    }, function () {
        console.log('connected to ' + config.host + ':' + config.port);
        client.write(move.forward, function () {
            console.log('move forward command sent');
        });
});

client.on('data', function (data)
 {
    var str = data.toString();

    if (str === 'ACK') 
    {

        setTimeout(function() 
        {   
            console.log('ACK received');
            client.write(move.backward, function () 
            {
                console.log('move backward sent');
                client.end();

            }); 
        }, 3000);

    }

});

client.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Error : ', err);
});

client.on('close', function () {
    console.log('socket closed');
});
```

Comment: Nice if it's working. If an answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as "selected answer". It will help people who will get there later :)

Comment: I don't think adding delay solve the problem of the write after end. The write after end error doesn't occured if - as you written on your code above - you put the client.end() in the callback function of the write method.
However, is the server is ending the connection at a time, and client-side you were writing data, the error occured.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to end your socket and re-open it again in your 'data' listener. You can keep the same socket.

Here is my `client.js` file which sends the commands:

```
var net = require('net');
var config = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 1850
};

var move = {
    forward: 'READER_FWD',
    backward: 'READER_BWD'
};

var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect({
        host: config.host,
        port: config.port
    }, function () {
        console.log('connected to ' + config.host + ':' + config.port);
        client.write(move.forward, function () {
            console.log('move forward command sent');
        });
});

client.on('data', function (data) {
    var str = data.toString();
    if (str === 'ACK') {
        console.log('ACK received');
        client.write(move.backward, function () {
            console.log('move backward sent');
            client.end();
        });
    }
});

client.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Error : ', err);
});

client.on('close', function () {
    console.log('socket closed');
});
```

The `connect()` method connects the socket to the server and send the forward command to it. It's exactly the same as yours.

Then, the problem comes from your 'data' listener. Your data listener must do the following things (as you mentionned in your description):

1. Get data from the server
2. If it's the ACK message: send the backward command
3. Then, close the connection (if needed; if not, keep it alive)

Be careful to the following point: the Socket [nodejs documentation for the event 'data'](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_data) says that we are receiving a `Buffer`. So you need to convert it to a `String` to compare with another String, using for this [the `.toString()` method of the Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end).

Thus, as is the Nodejs net.Socket is used with events, I don't think it is possible to send the forward command, listen to the 'data' event and send the backward command.

First, it is not a good idea, because you will put the on 'data' listener after the connection and it is possible that you will miss some data!
Secondly, as it is event based, you should create your architecture that follows the process :)

Below is my code for the server:

```
var net = require('net');
var port = 1850;
var move = {
    forward: 'READER_FWD',
    backward: 'READER_BWD'
};

var server = net.createServer(function (client) {
    console.log('client connected');

    client.on('end', function () {
        console.log('client disconnected');
    });

    client.on('data', function (data) {
        var str = data.toString();
        if (str === move.forward) {
            console.log('move forward command received');
            client.write('ACK', function () {
                console.log('ACK sent');
            });
        } else if (str === move.backward) {
            console.log('move backward command received: do nothing...');
        } else {
            console.log('unknown received message: ', str);
        }
    });
});

server.listen(port, function () { //'listening' listener
    console.log('server bound on port: ' + port);
});
```

Here are also the outputs if needed:

Server:

```
server bound on port: 1850
client connected
move forward command received
ACK sent
move backward command received: do nothing...
client disconnected
```

Client:

```
connected to 127.0.0.1:1850
move forward command sent
ACK received
move backward sent
socket closed
```

I hope it answers the question. Feel free to ask if there is anything.

Comment: i tried same approach before also, getting error connected to 127.0.0.1:1850
move forward command sent
ACK received
move backward sent
ACK received
Error :  [Error: write after end]
move backward sent
socket closed

Comment: @user3256190: there is a typo in my code. There is a `});` too many for the `client.connect` method. I'm gonna edit my post. Also, I don't know why you are getting two ACK. Do you have two servers running?

Comment: @user3256190 I don't know why you are getting two ACK. But for the error `Write after end`, I think you are calling the `client.end()` just after the `client.write()` and not in the write callback. Therefore, it closes the connection while still writing.

Comment: Ur right, whenever i send command to server it reply back with ACK.